# Updating Chosen Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen plugin and I got about 10 000 options in the dropdown. After user selects his option I want to reset chosen to it's default option. When liszt-update gets triggered it takes about 5 seconds for dropdown to render (as it contains so many options). Is there any way around it?

My code:

`$('#chosen_orgs').val('0').trigger('liszt:updated');`

Thanks.

Comment: huh very constructive and helpful answers. I wasn't asking about your opinion on usability.

Comment: @user1590158 Doesn't matter if you weren't asking - you're going to get opinions when you come here. Often, people use the wrong approach, and another set of eyes (or hundreds of sets of eyes that view questions) can help figure out a different approach that's "better". People are allowed to comment/ask questions in the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually update your original select instead.

```
$('#chosen_orgs, #original_select_id').val('0');
```

Also, just an FYI, [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is a much more well-developed fork of Chosen, and the syntax conversion is fairly simple.

Comment: Select2 is perfect. Thank you v.much for recommending it. `$('#dropdown).select2({minimumInputLength: 2});` is my choice of weapon.